# DatePicker not working in Rails app using link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a personal rails 5 app working on Heroku.  I'm using JQuery's DatePicker, which both works and doesn't work.  This issue applies to all pages I use DatePicker on, but I'll detail just my `hours/new` page/form. For context, this page is for entering hours worked for a job.

The form on `hours/new` uses JQuery's DatePicker. Note: the form is in a partial, though I do not think that is the cause.  The DatePicker does not work when I go to the page from a rails `link_to` link.  If I refresh the page or go to the page by manually entering the url, it works.  Just not when the pages loads from a `link_to` link.

On my `hours/index` view, which shows all records for hours worked, I have a link_to link to my `hours/new` page.

```
<p><%= link_to("Add Hours to a Job", new_hour_path) if request.env['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /hours/ %></p>
```

The link works and takes me to `hours/new`.  But, as stated, once there  DatePicker does not work, until I refresh the page

```
`hours/new.html.erb`
...
<td>Date Worked:</td>                                                    
<td><%= f.text_field :date_worked, { :size => 30, :type => 'date', :class => "date-picker", :readonly => true, :value => @hour.date_worked }  %></td>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker({
      inline: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
 });
</script>
```

I thought maybe datepicker js and/or css was not loading when I use `link_to`. But `view page source` does not show me anything different between the page loading from the `link_to` link or after a refresh.

I'm hoping someone might have an idea.
Thanks for any help.

Edited to add this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-18e947d2d91130fbb80f0509022a0c87588422bc9e0eea7df8075adabb315058.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
 <script src="/assets/application-69f3f74738bb36bc6230f4aaa10cb7c8cac5a93ae6ad83bcebea78dfd40d1031.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

Comment: Do you use Turbolinks?

Comment: I see `data-turbolinks-track="reload"` in the js and css links, but not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: The document.ready event is not enough for turbolinks. Try $(document).on('turbolinks:load',...)   https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

Comment: This works: `data: { turbolinks: false }`     `<%= link_to("Add Hours to a Job", new_hour_path,  data: { turbolinks: false }) if request.env['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /hours/ %>`

Comment: Thank you, @CodyCaughlan for the lead to a fix. Much appreciated.  And I learned something new.  2 somethings.